# How to find the last digit of $37^{100}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am currently working on some algebra and I am studying the modulus chapter of my book. One question was finding the last digit of:

$$37^{100}$$

They give a hint about how the solution should be about calculating a remainder...

Is there any easy solution to this?

I know that there is a solution of just finding the pattern of the last digit of $ 37^x$. But I don't understand how that has to do with calculating a remainder...

Thank you!

Comment: Last digit, you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Hint: What do you get if you look at some number mod $10$?

Comment: Use [Euler's totient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **last** digit of $37^{100}$ is the same as the last digit of $7^{100}$ or of $492038497^{100}$.

When you multiply two positive integers, the **last** digit in the product depends on those two integers only through **their last digits**.  That will become obvious if you look at the way they told you to multiply numbers by hand in third or fourth grade or whenever it was:
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
& & & 4 & 2 & 7 \\
& & \times & 3 & 1 & 9 \\
\hline
& & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & 3 \\
& & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
\hline
\bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & 3
\end{array}
$$
Where did that last $3$ come from??

Now multiply $7$, and discard all but the last digit:
\begin{align}
7 \times 7 & & & = \cdots\ 9 \\
7 \times 7 \times 7 & = (\cdots\ 9\times 7) & &= \cdots \bullet \\
7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 & = (\cdots \bullet\times 7) & & = \cdots \bullet \\
7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 \times 7 & = (\cdots \bullet\times 7) & & = \cdots\bullet \\
\end{align}
Just throw away all but the last digit at each step.

Now notice something: There are only $9$ digits that could possibly appear as the last digit (you can't get $0$ when you're multiplying non-zero digits).  That means you can't keep getting new digits there that you haven't seen before.

All this will lead you to see a **pattern** that occurs as you continue the process.  And you'll see **why** that happens.  And that will lead you quickly to the answer.

Comment: @LukasArvidsson: welcome ;)

Answer (score 9):

Since $37^2=1369$, then 
$$37^{100}=(37^2)^{50}=(1369)^{50}$$
and the last digit of $(1369)^{n}$ oscillates between $9$ if $n$ odd and $1$ if $n$ even.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

This is a question about calculating modulo 10.  So the last digit of $37^{100}$ is the same as the last digit of $7^{100}$; which is the same as the last digit of $49^{50}$, and so the same as the last digit of $9^{50}$.  Perhaps you can carry on from there.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it makes sense now ;)

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

You want to calculate the remainder after dividing by $10$. It's also good to know that $37^2$ has remainder $9$ after dividing by $10$, which may be written as $37^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

One finds the modulus of $37^{100}$ in decimal, by noting that in decimal, anything raised to the fourth power must end in $0$, $1$, $5$, or $6$.  When various powers of 5 are added, then the number must be adjent to a multiple of $5*5^n$, where $5^n$ divides the index.

So, we look for solutions, ending in any of these three digits:  $000$, $001$, $625$, or $376$, depending on what the common divisor with 10 is.  Here it's 1, so it ends in $001$.